# When I decorate a function why the original function becomes none type

Tags: python, decorator, python-decorators, nested-function

```
def outer_fun(func):
    print('outer function ran')

    def inner_function():
        print('inner function ran')

        return func()
    return inner_function()


def fun():
    print("Hi")


fun = outer_fun(fun)
print(fun)
```

the output is:

```
outer function ran
inner function ran
Hi
None
```

why the none here?

when I do

```
fun = outer_fun(fun)
```

and calls it immediately inside the `inner_function` it runs fun() and makes the fun a none object? why?
Also if I try to run `fun = outer_fun(fun)` again it says object is not callable

Comment: Function `fun` returns None (i.e. None is the default return value of a function call).

Answer (score 0):

`fun()` implicitly returns `None`.  So when you set

```py
fun = outer_fun(fun)
```

you have set `fun` to `None`.  Before that assignment, `fun` is a function.

When you repeat that call, `fun` is already `None`, so you are doing this:

```py
fun = outer_fun(None)
```

which as you note fails because `None` is not callable.

From the subject of your question, it seems you are trying to write a decorator.  Your decorator has to return a function (typically an inner function or closure).  If your decorator doesn't return anything, then you'll probably see the behavior you are trying to understand.

Your outer function ends with:

```py
return inner_function()
```

which should be:

```py
return inner_function
```

ie: return the function, not call the function and return whatever it returns.

Comment: ah it makes sense now.  Also when I do  `fun = outer_fun(fun)` Is the first fun now different than the second fun? Because outer_fun(fun) returns inner_function so the first fun should be assigned that but the second fun is still the original fun().

Comment: When you call `outer_fun(fun)` you are passing the originally defined `fun` as the argument.  When you set `fun` to the return value of `outer_fun(fun)`, `fun` is now the newly created inner function returned by `outer_fun`.  The original `fun` no longer exists.  That's the essence of what a decorator does.

Answer (score 0):

In a simple word your `None` is occur for this code

```
def fun():
    print("Hi")
```

because its return Nothing, if you return something then it can show this instead of `None`. If you don't want to see `None` then use `fun` instead of `print(fun)`.